# convert number from base 10 to base 7 numeric c#

Tags: c#, .net, int, radix

With Convert.ToString Method in c# i can only convert numbers to base 2, 8, 10, or 16. is there a way to Convert/calculate base 10 number to base 7 with c# .net4 or 4.5?

[MSDN Convert.ToString Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Surely your teacher expects you to submit *your* solution, not ours.  If you are stuck implementing this then you have not give us any hint exactly *where* you got stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You can check [this blog](http://www.pvladov.com/2012/05/decimal-to-arbitrary-numeral-system.html) which gives a solution for this:

```
public static string DecimalToArbitrarySystem(long decimalNumber, int radix)
{
    const int BitsInLong = 64;
    const string Digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if (radix < 2 || radix > Digits.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("The radix must be >= 2 and <= " +
            Digits.Length.ToString());

    if (decimalNumber == 0)
        return "0";

    int index = BitsInLong - 1;
    long currentNumber = Math.Abs(decimalNumber);
    char[] charArray = new char[BitsInLong];

    while (currentNumber != 0)
    {
        int remainder = (int)(currentNumber % radix);
        charArray[index--] = Digits[remainder];
        currentNumber = currentNumber / radix;
    }

    string result = new String(charArray, index + 1, BitsInLong - index - 1);
    if (decimalNumber < 0)
    {
        result = "-" + result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then call it like

```
Console.WriteLine("Base 7: " + DecimalToArbitrarySystem(number,  7));
```

Comment: Math.Abs(decimalNumber) will generate an exception if decimalNumber is equal to long.MinValue. Very easy to forget!

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to convert this solution to Vb.Net and the result was always wrong using all the C# to VB.Net online converter. The problem was with the integer division.
(You can try to calculate 320 in radix 5 (C#=2240 is OK. Using the conversion to VB.Net the result is always 13340 witch is wrong).

Here is the solution in VB.Net

```
Public Shared Function DecimalToArbitrarySystem(ByVal decimalNumber As Long, ByVal radix As Integer) As String
        Const BitsInLong As Integer = 64
        Const Digits As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        If radix < 2 OrElse radix > Digits.Length Then Throw New ArgumentException("The radix must be >= 2 and <= " & Digits.Length.ToString())
        If decimalNumber = 0 Then Return "0"
        Dim index As Integer = BitsInLong - 1
        Dim currentNumber As Long = Math.Abs(decimalNumber)
        Dim charArray As Char() = New Char(63) {}

        While currentNumber <> 0
            Dim remainder As Integer = CInt((currentNumber Mod radix))
            charArray(index) = Digits(remainder)
            index -= 1
            currentNumber = currentNumber \ radix
        End While

        Dim result As String = New String(charArray, index + 1, BitsInLong - index - 1)

        If decimalNumber < 0 Then
            result = "-" & result
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
```